# TF2 plugin signature (Source SDK)

Tags: server, plugin, valve

I am working on the server plugin for TF2. I need it for getting some stats from game (no hacking and cheating). My problem: I got message "No valid signature found..." while testing my plugin. But I want to make my plugin public in future (maybe).

Please tell me about signing procedure. How can I get valid signature for my plugin? What I must to do (send my plugin to Valve or what else)?

Comment: Is this a dedicated server plugin or a client plugin?

Comment: it is dedicated plugin, must be installed on server

Answer (score 3):

Two types of plugins:

**Server Plugins:** are C++ code libraries that modify the behaviour of dedicated servers.

**Client plugins:** are server plugins running in a client (rather than a dedicated server). They have access to client interfaces that dedicated servers cannot provide.

From the [Source documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Client_plugins):

> Client plugins must be signed by Valve before they can be loaded -
>   [you'll have to email and ask](http://www.valvesoftware.com/email.php?recipient=Robin%20Walker). During development, run the game in
>   -insecure mode to bypass the signature check.

I imagine the process is the same for server plugins, the documentation is mute on that. That's my best guess. Probably your best bet is to email Robin Walker and ask.